# Enabling Offline when internet will off

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing a chat application using firebase with ionic 3. I have to change status to 'offline' when disconnected from the internet.

I have referred to the following sites:

1) https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

2) https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

```
this.disconnectSubscription = this.network
    .onDisconnect()
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.online = false;
        var userLastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/'this.loggedInUserId);
        userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set({status:offline});
    });
```

When I turn off the internet connection the status of `offline` will not get changed.

Comment: This line `var userLastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/'this.loggedInUserId);` looks suspicious to me as there's no string concatenation going on. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No not any error, have you check that two links, am I going correct?

Comment: so what are you using to detect online or offline state?

Comment: How did you test this? And how long did you wait? In the case of a "dirty" disconnect (e.g. the network connection suddenly dropping), Firebase's server-side `onDisconnect()` logic depends on the socket state to detect that the client is gone. This can take up to several minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for online and offline event like this

```
window.addEventListener("online", this.doSomethingWhenOnline);
window.addEventListener("offline", this.doSomethingWhenOffline);

doSomethingWhenOnline() {

}

doSomethingWhenOffline() {

}
```

Comment: I have tried it but how can I trigger to fire base if internet connection lost, i.e my big issue

Comment: Put that in ngOnInit of app.component.ts